# Вложенный цикл вызывает утечку памяти

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с вложенным масивом, который проверяет, есть ли у двух массивов общее значение определённого ключа. Но почему-то при работе такого скрипта зависает вкладка, съедая полтора гигабайта оперативной памяти. Хотя в скрипте нет ничего сверхсложного:

```
for(let i = 0; i < temp_props.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < proposals.length; j++) {
        if(temp_props[i].sign == proposals[j].sign) {
            proposals[j].terms.push(temp_props[i].terms[0])
        } else {
            proposals.push(temp_props[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Почему вообще происходит утечка?

**UPD:** а почему вот тут всё зависает? Я же в `proposals` не пушу новые элементы, а только изменяю существующие(`proposals.length` не меняется же):

```
if(proposals.length == 0) {
    for(let i = 0; i < iteration_proposals.length; i++) {
        proposals.push(iteration_proposals[i]);
    }
} else {
    let others_props = [];
    let other_terms = [];

    for(let j = 0; j < iteration_proposals.length; j++) {
        for(let i = 0; i < proposals.length; i++) {
            if(iteration_proposals[j].sign == proposals[i].sign)
                (proposals[i].terms).push(iteration_proposals[j].terms[0]);
            else
                others_props.push(iteration_proposals[j]);
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < others_props.length; i++) {
        proposals.push(others_props[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что ты изменяешь массив, по которому бежишь

Comment: После `proposals.push` значение `proposals.length` увеличивается, в результате цикл никогда не может добежать до конца массива, потому что он всё время увеличивается

Comment: @Grundy вот сейчас сделал подгрузку `proposals` в локальный массив перед циклом, по нему прошёлся, а затем просто перезаписал большой массив. А всё равно подвисает.

Comment: я не удивлюсь. если ты просто ссылку в другую переменную перезаписал и у тебя на самом деле все точно так же осталось работать

Comment: @Grundy что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Очевидно, не изменять массив, по которому совершается обход.

Comment: @Grundy, да ладно 0.0!

Comment: @Grundy просмотрите, пожалуйста, обновлённую версию вопроса.

Comment: какое количество элементов в массивах?

Comment: @Grundy в среднем 1000.

Comment: то есть 1000*1000 - миллион итераций, не такое большое количество, чтобы почувствовать зависание, значит либо код отличается, либо внутри цикла выполняется что-то тяжелое, либо количество элементов существенно больше

Comment: @Grundy сейчас попытался отловить количество вставляемых данных и вот что обнаружил. В тот блок, где два `for`-итератора, прилетает массив с 409 элементами. А вот когда эти два цикла заканчиваю работу, то `others_props.lenth` равняется 409777. Я был немного в шоке с этих цифр. Ошибка и зависание происходило там, где цикл пытался уже эти 409777 элементов вставить в `proposals`.

Comment: @Grundy есть идеи, почему так получается? Не могу разобраться :(

Comment: без примера кода воспроизводящего ошибку - нет.

Comment: @Grundy в общем, я разобрался с проблемой. Если выполняется условие `if`, то мой код отрабатывает нормально. А вот если условие не удовлетворяется, то один и тот же элемент запушится в массив `proposals.length` раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Касаемо первого вопроса(до UPD):** как верно подметили [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) и [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal), нельзя изменять массив, итерируемый циклом. Решил эту проблему тем, что перед циклом создавал `let temporary = []` массив, пушил в него результат, а по окончанию основного цикла брал всё, что насобиралось в `temporary`, и вставлял в глобальный массив.

**Касаемо второго вопроса(в UPD)**: проблема была в том, что во вложенном цикле проверялись все элементы. И если какой-то один элемент удовлетворил условию и успешно запушился в глобальный массив, то все остальные пушились в `temporary` *proposals.length раз*. Как вариант решения такой проблемы я рассматриваю проверку на дубли во временном массиве. Если условие и зашло в else, то перед пушем массива в `temporary` нужно проверять, а нет ли там уже такого массива. Если моё суждение не верно и это можно сделать проще - рад буду каждому совету. Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: Вместо того чтобы убирать дубли из массива - их туда можно просто не класть. Посмотрите внимательнее на ваши внутренний цикл и условие - они идут в неправильном порядке.